# Using Vision Caltech Camera Calibration toolbox for MATLAB

Tags: matlab, camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

I am currently using the camera calibration toolbox from vision caltech:http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/example.html

It has been good so far and I was able to obtain the camera parameters of my camera and everything using the checkered board.

So now I have been taking pictures with my camera and I want to undistort them using the calibration results I obtained from the caltech calibration toolbox.

The parameters are saved in a .mat file but I cannot find a way to use them on other images I took.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks;

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18804182/2777181

Comment: the paramaters that are output are generally the intrinsic properties of the camera, ie, the focal length, etc.... it also depends on whether it is an affine distortion or a non-linear distortion. If it is an affine distortion you would just set up a simple homography to "undistort" the image. Assuming its just a linear distortion you could just find the "undistorted" points by applying homography. Not sure if this helps, but hopefully it can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [easier way to calibrate cameras in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/camera-calibration-with-matlab-81233.html). The Computer Vision System Toolbox also includes the `undistortImage` function, which is what you are looking for.